# Backwards Compatibility of Enum Additions for Objectify/Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, enums, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

We are using Objectify with Google App Engine for Java.  We are persisting a variety of enum constants in the datastore using the supplied [EnumTranslatorFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/4.0b1/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/EnumTranslatorFactory.java) which simply stores/loads the constant using the [Enum#name()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29). This works well.

When we release new versions of our app to GAE, the new version lives next to the old version(s) both serving requests simultaneously to clients. This is explained well by [Google's traffic splitting docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting).

Upgrades to the system introduce new Enum constants which cause errors during loading.  For example:

Version 1 has the following enum:

```
enum Meal{BREAKFAST,LUNCH,DINNER}
```

Version 2 has the additional constant added to the enum to support British meals:

```
enum Meal{BREAKFAST,LUNCH,TEA,DINNER}
```

While testing version 2 of the app, TEA will be persisted with some Entity.  Subsequently Version 1 will load that Entity, Objectify will attempt to convert TEA into a Enum using Enum#valueOf(...) which throws a runtime exception.

Objectify docs explain [Data Migration](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/SchemaMigration) for Enums, but it doesn't satisfy the above situation.

I'm interested in suggestions about how to best handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, provide an Interface that will provide a default value if the enum is not known.

```
public interface EnumWithDefault<E extends Enum<E>> {
    E getDefault();
}
```

An Enum that may have future additions should implement this Interface:

```
public enum MyEnum implements EnumWithDefault<MyEnum>{
  ENUM_IN_VERSION_1, FUTURE;

  public MyEnum getDefault(){ return FUTURE; }
}
```

Register a TranslatorFactory that will provide default if implemented:

```
       return new ValueTranslator<Enum<?>, String>(path, String.class) {
    @Override
    public Enum<?> loadValue(String value, LoadContext ctx) {
        try{
           return Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>)type, value.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
           if (EnumWithDefault.class.isAssignableFrom(enumType)) {
                EnumWithDefault<E> any = (EnumWithDefault<E>) enumType.getEnumConstants()[0];
                result = any.getDefault();
           }else{
              throw e;
           } 
        }
    }
```

Version 2 deployed with new Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum implements EnumWithDefault<MyEnum>{
  ENUM_IN_VERSION_1, ENUM_IN_VERSION_2, FUTURE;

  public MyEnum getDefault(){ return FUTURE; }
}
```

When Version 2 of the app is deployed and ENUM_IN_VERSION_2 is stored in the datastore related to some Entity, the response differs when hitting the endpoints of the two versions.

Hitting the first version returns the value FUTURE allowing the client to present an appropriate message:

```
http://1.myapi.appspot.com/entities
```

returns:

```
<myEntity id='xyz' category='FUTURE' />
```

Hitting version 2 provides the new enum:

```
http://2.myapi.appspot.com/entities
```

returns:

```
<myEntity id='xyz' category='ENUM_IN_VERSION_2' />
```

This solution allows additional enumerations to be added and used in a later release while older versions present a value to the client per the contract that "Future" is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would suggest making two upgrades to your app. First, make an upgrade that only understands the new enum value (but never writes it) and spread that throughout your system. Then make a release that actually writes the new values.

Data migrations are hard, especially when you want to use traffic splitting. Break it into steps and multiple deploys.

Comment: Your suggestion is likely scenario and one that we are using in the case of a rename of an enum for code maintenance purposes.  However, for additions we wish to use the new enum with new features and it is painful to build the new feature and not use it.  We hope to keep these multiple versions running side-by-side for several weeks or months so our features would be held hostage by this enum limitation.

Comment: I'm not really sure what kind of solution you are looking for. You want to write some new data to the datastore that an old version of your app does not understand. There is no magic, you need to make your old version handle the new data gracefully before you can change the data structure. This applies to any kind of migration, not just enums.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own custom EnumTranslatorFactory that provides a *null* for any value not yet known.

```
        ....
            return new ValueTranslator<Enum<?>, String>(path, String.class) {
        @Override
        public Enum<?> loadValue(String value, LoadContext ctx) {
            try{
               return Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>)type, value.toString());
            }catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }

        ...
```

This is not ideal because the property may be required and other code may fail if a null is provided.  All properties that are persisted enums in the code base must be @Nullable.